# PDF: An image could not be created from the given input

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I am using [Spatie\PdfToImage](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/pdf-to-image) in my Symfony application to change PDFs into images. Here is the function I am using:

```
public function savePdfPreviewImage($fullFilePath, $thumbnailPath)
{
    $pdf = new Pdf($fullFilePath);
    $pdf->saveImage($thumbnailPath); 

    return $this;
}
```

When given a path to a PDF, the library returns this message:

> An image could not be created from the given input

**How can I go about finding a solution to this?**

So far I have tried verifying with an `ls` that the file exists in the place where the app thinks it is. I have also tried opening the file -- which has a `.pdf` file extension -- in a PDF reader to verify that it is not corrupt. Neither of those two actions yielded any clues.

=====

Edit 1: I traced this message back to the `Imagine.php` file, where I removed an error-suppression line. That gave me this slightly less opaque message:

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

====

Edit 2: I have also verified that ghostscript is installed. The `gs` command is available from my server environment. I have also verified that the path provided for `$thumbnailPath` is a valid path/filename ending in .jpg.

Comment: Have you verified that the input image is in proper format? Can you enhance the debug level to see whether any more obvious message is printed?

Comment: Have your tried other pdf-files? Try to use a simple onepage-file to verify if it doesn't work at all or just doesn't work with certain files.

Comment: I have tried it with four different PDF files, including a single-page file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

The conversion to PDF was actually behaving just fine. What was misbehaving was a later call within the application to the Imagine.php library, unsuccessfully resizing the image that my code successfully created. Here is the code that allowed me to see this:

```
public function savePdfPreviewImage($fullFilePath, $thumbnailPath)
{

      //$pdf = new Pdf($fullFilePath);
      //$pdf->saveImage($thumbnailPath);    //This gives us "An image could not be created from the given input" and "Data is not in a recognized format"
                                            //Let's try it with a manual call to GhostScript instead ...

    exec(
        'gs -o ' .                //This creates the image successfully, but the error still shows up.
        $thumbnailPath .                    //That means the error isn't coming from here, since we're no longer calling any external PHP libraries.
        ' -sDEVICE=jpeg ' .
        $fullFilePath
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a lib for this, imagick alone will do fine.

```
$pdf = new \Imagick();
$pdf->setColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
$pdf->readImage($srcPath);
$pdf->setIteratorIndex($pageNo);
$pdf->writeImage($outPath);
```

(Imagick will recognize the file extension from $outPath)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still get "An image could not be created from the given input"

Comment: This is at best a workaround, but likely not an answer at all.

Comment: When 5 lines allow you to drop a dependency, it is definitely worth it. According to OP, the problem was with the resizing, but there was no indication to that in the question.

Comment: Well, that might be. But there might be a good reason to use the library in this project, but this question itself doesn't give enough information about this. And a good advice doesn't make a good answer.